# cannot add foreign key to mysql table through python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create three tables in MySQL, here is the code

```
TABLES['MACHINE'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `MACHINE` ("
    "  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `x` int NOT NULL ,"
    "  `y` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `machineid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `sitename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `version_PK` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "   `r` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `s` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `re` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `dd` DATETIME NOT NULL,"
    "  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `latitude` float  ,"
    "  `longitude` float ,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),"
    " unique key (`machineid`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
TABLES['JOB'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `JOB` ("
    "  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `machine_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `sl` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `sc` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `vercsion_PK` int NOT NULL,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),"
    "  CONSTRAINT `JOB_1` FOREIGN KEY (`machine_id`) "
    "        REFERENCES `MACHINE` (`machineid`) ON DELETE CASCADE"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

TABLES['SCAN_PASS'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `SCAN_PASS` ("
    "  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `job_id` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `dates` DATETIME NOT NULL,"
    "  `pass` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `rawdata` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `units` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `afterpass` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `version_PK` int NOT NULL,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),"
    "  CONSTRAINT `SCAN_1` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) "
    "        REFERENCES `JOB` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")


for name, ddl in TABLES.iteritems():
    cursor.execute(ddl)

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

the problem is I am getting this error when running the code "IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')"

what confuses me is that when I change the third table's name to anything else other than scan_pass. everything seems to work fine. 
this code is generating the database and then creating these table, I just did not include the code that generate the database. also there are no other tables in MySQL server that has the same name "scan_pass" in any other data bases. 
why does it only complain when the table's name is "scan_pass"? I really need to have a table with this name. 
thanks for any help in advance

Comment: It seems fine to me. Actually I ran three CREATE TABLE myself. It went thru without error. I assume that they don't exist initially. Perhaps it's caching problem? One thing though, if you have id in MACHINE table, you have some reason not to use its id as FK in JOB? If you use machineid column as a FK, you don't need id in MACHINE.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to solve the caching problem ? any ideas of what can be done?